# Slice or substring on search query mongoose so it fits the given parameter it is returning empty

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use query search in mongoose when user hast array of objects with different postalCodes.
And I have an object which is called Job.
At job I have postalCode as String.
What I want to achieve it is for each postalCode from users to slice the postalCode on jobs and if possible to match them.
Problem it is that always it is returning empty but in case it should match with the job and return it.
User it is always the logged in user.
So user is the given input to search into the collection of jobs

Here is my Code of 1 user.

```
"searchFilter" : {
    "remote" : 0,
    "data" : [
        {
            
            "country" : "DEU",
            "searchActive" : false,
            "postalCode" : "123",
            "available" : {
                "$date" : 1664955924380
            }
        },
        {
            
            "country" : "DEU",
            "searchActive" : false,
            "postalCode" : "850",
            "available" : {
                "$date" : 1667165151744
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

And this is the job.

```
"postalCode" : "12345",
"country" : "DEU",
```

And this is my actual query search.

```
 let job = await Job.find({
  
                $or: user.searchFilter.data.map((user) => user.postalCode)
                .map((postalCode) => ( {
                      yearSubstring: { $substr: [ "$postalCode", 0, postalCode.length ] },                
              }))

            
});

if (!job) {
   res.status(204).json({ error: "No Data" });
   return;
 }
return res.status(200).send(job);
```

Comment: Is the job given, or are you using a collection of jobs that you want to run through?

Comment: It is not clear if a given `user` or a given `job` are the inputs of the query

Comment: User is a given input and it will search on jobs collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `$in` operator to find the string from a provided array of strings,

```
let job = await Job.find({
  postalCode: { 
    $in: user.searchFilter.data.map(user => user.postalCode) 
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/faXzCH1A7r1)

If you want to search the substring or inside the string then you can use `$regex` operator,

```
let job = await Job.find({
  postalCode: { 
    $regex: user.searchFilter.data.map(user => user.postalCode).join("|")
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YM5L8BN3RkA)

Comment: This is the way to go if the user is known, but I think there is a small change needed, the expression should be at the start, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rQgQ7yfp_zB)

Comment: Right, it is up to OP, that is not clear about search in question and what exactly he wants...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is close to this:

1. First find the logged user
2. `unwind` to divide its `data` to different documents
3. Get the relevant `jobs` for each `data` item
4. Keep only `data` items that has a `job`.
5. An optional step is to `$group` all the relevant `data` items of the `user` to one document (can be seen on the playground link below)

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: {}}, // here use the logged user identifier
  {$unwind: "$searchFilter.data"},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "jobs",
      let: {postalCode: "$searchFilter.data.postalCode"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                {$substr: ["$postalCode", 0, {$strLenCP: "$$postalCode"}]},
                "$$postalCode"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "jobs"
    }
  },
  {$match: {"jobs.0": {$exists: true}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DL5NqdcFHG7)

Comment: I have the logged user so I can read its data. I meed only relevant jobs which matches postal code of the user.

Comment: @nimrokserok I want to search Jobs and not users.
Because for each logged user he/she can search jobs collection

Comment: If you already have the user in hand, use @turivishal's answer